# Print Window of a windows store app in c++ in win32 app

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-store-apps, snapshot

We can print window of win32 app by passing its window handle to PrintWindow function.

Although windows store apps also have HWND in windows 10, i am still unable to print window for modern apps by above function.

I searched for other API which can print windows of modern apps also, but could not get anything on this topic.

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I have a similar question out there and found yours:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931890/how-to-capture-window-contents-of-a-windows-store-app-in-c-sharp